# Angular2 Typescript pass string to url string

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently switched from Angular 1 to Angular2 and I need to clarify some things .

I have this code .

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'google-maps',
  template: `<div id="map"></div>`
})

export class GoogleMaps{
  maps_key : string = "1234string1234";
  visible : boolean = false;

  constructor(element : ElementRef) {
    GoogleMapsService.load().then(() => {
      this.visible = true;
      console.log('maps is ready to show');
    });
  }


}

class GoogleMapsService{

  static script;

  static load(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if(!GoogleMapsService.script){
        GoogleMapsService.script = document.createElement('script');
        GoogleMapsService.script.src = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**SET_KEY_HERE**';
        document.body.appendChild(GoogleMapsService.script);
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

How can i pass maps_key string from GoogleMaps class to GoogleMapsService *SET_KEY_HERE*

Comment: Pass it as argument to the load() method? Why is this value defined in the component class rather than the GoogleMapsService class in the first place?

Comment: @JBNizet I am a complete beginner in Typescript, do not really know how to well organize code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it to the `load` function like this

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'google-maps',
  template: `<div id="map"></div>`
})

export class GoogleMaps{
  visible : boolean = false;

  constructor(element : ElementRef) {
    GoogleMapsService.load().then(() => {
      this.visible = true;
      console.log('maps is ready to show');
    });
  }


}

class GoogleMapsService{

  static script;
  static maps_key : string = "1234string1234";

  static load(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if(!GoogleMapsService.script){
        GoogleMapsService.script = document.createElement('script');
        GoogleMapsService.script.src = `//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GoogleMapsService.maps_key}`;
        document.body.appendChild(GoogleMapsService.script);
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: and you can keep the keys to the `GoogleMapsService` it self as JB Nizet suggested. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I would to know if there is any way to pass variable to string as in javascript for ex : *"string"* + _variable_ + *"string"*, other than using `` which is used from angular2 template

Comment: I think you have to concatenate the `variable`.